# How to extend fullCalendar.js end date using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634772/fullcalendar-end-date-is-not-inclusive) guy. I don't know how to increase the end date by one day. I don't want to change its value in the database, just on the html page.

Here's my calendar at the moment (no Moment.js pun):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
   var base_url = '{{ url('/') }}';
   var $calendar = $('#calendar-holidays').fullCalendar({
   header: {
      left: '',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
      },
   weekends: false,
   editable: false,
   eventLimit: true,
   events: {
      url: base_url + '/holidayapi',
      error: function () {
         alert("cannot load holidays from database");
      },
   }
});
```

Comment: what end date? could you make a fiddle? i don't quite get your question.

Comment: The JSON feed to the calendar is composed of a start date and an end date for every event in the database.

Comment: What version of moment, fullcalendar, jquery libraries?

Comment: @smcd It is version 2. I use fullcalendar.min.js, jquery ui core (latest), along with its widget, mouse, and draggable libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your event objects have end specified

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  /* assumes end is set in event object! */
  eventDataTransform: function(event) {
    var copy = $.extend({}, event);
    copy.end = moment(event.end).add(1, 'day'); // make moment in case it isn't already
    return copy;
  },
  events: [{ /* sample event */
    start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    // all day event, assumes end to be next day @ 00:00
    end: moment().add(1,'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    title: 'Today event'
  }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, end was specified.